# pytorch - connection between loss.backward() and optimizer.step()

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, pytorch, gradient-descent

Where is an explicit connection between the `optimizer` and the `loss`?

How does the optimizer know where to get the gradients of the loss without a call liks this `optimizer.step(loss)`?

-More context-

When I minimize the loss, I didn't have to pass the gradients to the optimizer.

```
loss.backward() # Back Propagation
optimizer.step() # Gradient Descent
```

Answer (score 140, accepted):

Without delving too deep into the internals of pytorch, I can offer a simplistic answer:

Recall that when initializing `optimizer` you explicitly tell it what parameters (tensors) of the model it should be updating. The gradients are "stored" by the tensors themselves (they have a [`grad`](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/autograd.html#torch.Tensor.grad) and a [`requires_grad`](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/autograd.html#torch.Tensor.requires_grad) attributes) once you call `backward()` on the loss. After computing the gradients for all tensors in the model, calling `optimizer.step()` makes the optimizer iterate over all parameters (tensors) it is supposed to update and use their internally stored `grad` to update their values.

More info on computational graphs and the additional "grad" information stored in pytorch tensors can be found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63869655/1714410).

Referencing the parameters by the optimizer can sometimes cause troubles, e.g., when the model is moved to GPU *after* initializing the optimizer.
Make sure you are done setting up your model *before* constructing the optimizer. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66096687/1714410) for more details.

Comment: @Aerin it's not a trivial connection... One would have expect `optimizer.step` to get `loss.backward()` as an argument. However, it all happens "behind the curtain"...

Comment: So how does optimizer.step() get the gradient value from loss.backward(). It seems that this answer hasn't answered the mechanism for the "connection".

Optimizer has reference to model parameters. But loss function is completely on its own. It doens't look like it has reference to model or optimizer.

Comment: @cfeng the loss function is not on its own at all! It is the final leaf in a single gigantic computational graph which starts with the model inputs and contains all model parameters. This graph is computed for each batch and results in a single scalar number on each batch. When we do `loss.backward()` the process of backpropagation starts at the loss and goes through all of its parents all the way to model inputs. All nodes in the graph contain a reference to their parent.

Comment: @mofury The question isn't that simple to answer in short. Roughly speaking, first, the instance of a loss function class, say, an instance of the `nn.CrossEntropyLoss` can be called and return a `Tensor`. That's important, this `Tensor` object has a `grad_fn` prop in which there stores tensors it is derived from. And those tensors also have such a prop so that the `backward` function can do a backpropagation through such props and eventually arrive at the parameters we want to optimize in the model. You can refer to this: https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/basics/autogradqs_tutorial.html.

Comment: is it correct to say that optimizer.step is only used in train phase and not in validation phase? I am aware that loss.backward is only used in train phase and not in validation phase. If it is correct, I am then confused why we then would bother with zeroing validation phase optimizer gradients using optimizer.zero_grad.

Comment: @MonaJalal where did you see an optimizer in a validation code? Optimizer has nothing to do with validation/test

Comment: https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/finetuning_torchvision_models_tutorial.html#inception-v3 uses optimizer.zero_grad also for validation phase which I think shouldn't

Comment: I modified it to https://pastebin.com/raw/0QH7FHnj for myself

Comment: @MonaJalal there is no optimizer in the code snippet you pasted, or am I missing something? Don't confuse `torxh.no_grad()` with `optimizer.zero_grad()`: these are two completely different things

Comment: well, I believe we should use torch.no_grad for evaluation mode.

Answer (score 58):

When you call `loss.backward()`, all it does is compute gradient of loss w.r.t all the parameters in loss that have `requires_grad = True` and store them in `parameter.grad` attribute for every parameter.

`optimizer.step()` updates all the parameters based on `parameter.grad`

Comment: `loss` is computing the loss between two tensors with no relation to a network. How does `loss.backward()` know which network it needs to reference and compute `parameter.grad` for?

Comment: @AzizAlfoudari see my answer for a clarification attempt :).

Answer (score 57):

Perhaps this will clarify a little the connection between `loss.backward` and `optim.step` (although the other answers are to the point).

```
# Our "model"
x = torch.tensor([1., 2.], requires_grad=True)
y = 100*x

# Compute loss
loss = y.sum()

# Compute gradient of the loss w.r.t. to the parameters  
print(x.grad)     # None
loss.backward()      
print(x.grad)     # tensor([100., 100.])

# MOdify the parameters by subtracting the gradient
optim = torch.optim.SGD([x], lr=0.001)
print(x)        # tensor([1., 2.], requires_grad=True)
optim.step()
print(x)        # tensor([0.9000, 1.9000], requires_grad=True)
```

`loss.backward()` sets the `grad` attribute of all tensors with `requires_grad=True`
in the computational graph of which loss is the leaf (only `x` in this case).

Optimizer just iterates through the list of parameters (tensors) it received on initialization and everywhere where a tensor has `requires_grad=True`, it subtracts the value of its gradient stored in its `.grad` property (simply multiplied by the learning rate in case of SGD). It doesn't need to know with respect to what loss the gradients were computed it just wants to access that `.grad` property so it can do `x = x - lr * x.grad`

**Note** that if we were doing this in a train loop we would call `optim.zero_grad()` because in each train step we want to compute new gradients - we don't care about gradients from the previous batch. Not zeroing grads would lead to gradient accumulation across batches.

Comment: I like this kind of "hands on" explanation to understand things. Thanks, makes much more sense to me!

Comment: It should be "Compute gradients of the loss w.r.t. the parameters."

Answer (score 35):

Some answers explained well, but I'd like to give a specific example to explain the mechanism.

Suppose we have a function : z = 3 x^2 + y^3.
The updating gradient formula of z w.r.t x and y is:

[image]

initial values are x=1 and y=2.

```
x = torch.tensor([1.0], requires_grad=True)
y = torch.tensor([2.0], requires_grad=True)
z = 3*x**2+y**3

print("x.grad: ", x.grad)
print("y.grad: ", y.grad)
print("z.grad: ", z.grad)

# print result should be:
x.grad:  None
y.grad:  None
z.grad:  None
```

Then calculating the gradient of x and y in current value (x=1, y=2)

[image]

```
# calculate the gradient
z.backward()

print("x.grad: ", x.grad)
print("y.grad: ", y.grad)
print("z.grad: ", z.grad)

# print result should be:
x.grad:  tensor([6.])
y.grad:  tensor([12.])
z.grad:  None
```

Finally, using SGD optimizer to update the value of x and y according the formula:
[image]

```
# create an optimizer, pass x,y as the paramaters to be update, setting the learning rate lr=0.1
optimizer = optim.SGD([x, y], lr=0.1)

# executing an update step
optimizer.step()

# print the updated values of x and y
print("x:", x)
print("y:", y)

# print result should be:
x: tensor([0.4000], requires_grad=True)
y: tensor([0.8000], requires_grad=True)
```

Comment: This is a great explanation along with the code. Thanks.

Comment: Very good explanations, the analogy with the real example is great honestly

Answer (score 31):

Let's say we defined a model: `model`, and loss function: `criterion` and we have the following sequence of steps:

```
pred = model(input)
loss = criterion(pred, true_labels)
loss.backward()
```

`pred` will have an `grad_fn` attribute, that references a function that created it, and ties it back to the model. Therefore, `loss.backward()` will have information about the model it is working with.

Try removing `grad_fn` attribute, for example with:

```
pred = pred.clone().detach()
```

Then the model gradients will be `None` and consequently weights will not get updated.

And the optimizer is tied to the model because we pass `model.parameters()` when we create the optimizer.

Comment: shouldn't it be "Then the models **gradients** will not get updated.", since loss.backward() updates the gradients?

Comment: @zwithouta, Thanks, this is a good point. I updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks, the fact that grad_fn it the tensor is a reference to the model was the missing piece of the puzzle for me.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe some of you are still a little confused because of the way the loss is being called.

These are the main 3 steps to make the backprop and then update parameters.

```
loss = loss_function(y_hat, Y_train)
loss.backward()
optimizer.step()
```

I was lost about the connection, but the key is the loss definition call. Every loss function returns a Tensor as well. This tensor includes ALL the parameters used to calculate y_hat and also the Y_train parameters (this won't be a problem because of the observer in the optimizer).

When you declare an optimizer you'll add as an argument the params that needs to observed.

```
optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(params=model.parameters(), lr=0.001)
```

This means that, when the optimizers is called, it's going to calculate all the gradients (or derivatives) of the model AND THAT implies the gradients stored on y_hat (and not Y_train because is not included in the observer).

So the connection between the loss and the optim is y_hat or prediction output that contains the common grads from the model.

To summarize

```
#Some model created
model = MyModel() 

#Optimizer to use
optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(params=model_1.parameters(), lr=0.001) 

#Loss function to apply
loss_function = torch.nn.L1Loss() 

#The output of this call is a Tensor with all the parameters from the model
loss = loss_function(y_hat, Y_train) 

#This is going to calculate the gradients of the values of y_hat (same as model)
loss.backward() 

#Inside each parameter there is already a grad calculated, this only applies the gradient descent algorithm to the observed parameters
optimizer.step()
```

Answer (score -2):

Short answer:

`loss.backward()` # do gradient of all parameters for  which we set `required_grad= True`. parameters could be any variable defined in code, like `h2h` or `i2h`.

`optimizer.step()` # according to the optimizer function (defined previously in our code), we update those parameters to finally get the minimum loss(error).