# RuntimeError: Expected all tensors to be on the same device, but found at least two devices, cuda:0 and cpu! in simple chatbot codes

Tags: python, pytorch, gpu, cpu

I made my first Korean chatbot program with python, pytorch and pycharm. It works in my local environment but so slow, So I want to move my codes to Google Colab to make it fast. But I have runtime error : two devices(cuda and cpu) works in same space. I looked for this error and found out that I should upload all of my codes to GPU to work correctly. However, I added .to(device) / .tocuda() something like this for several times but it wasn't worked yet. Please help me. Below this text, this is my whole train codes : Trainer.py and I have problem when call this code to other one. (Import trainer)

```
import aboutDataSets
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import torch
from tqdm import tqdm # 학습 진행률 시각화 1
from time import sleep # 학습 진행률 시각화 2
import re  # 정규식 계산
import os
import urllib.request  # url로 csv파일 받아오기
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader, Dataset
from transformers.optimization import AdamW  # optimizer
from transformers import PreTrainedTokenizerFast, GPT2LMHeadModel

Q_TKN = "<usr>"
A_TKN = "<sys>"
BOS = '</s>'
EOS = '</s>'
MASK = '<unused0>'
SENT = '<unused1>'
PAD = '<pad>'

tokenizer = PreTrainedTokenizerFast.from_pretrained("skt/kogpt2-base-v2",
                                                    bos_token=BOS,
                                                    eos_token=BOS,
                                                    unk_token='unk',
                                                    pad_token=PAD,
                                                    mask_token=MASK)
model = GPT2LMHeadModel.from_pretrained('skt/kogpt2-base-v2')
urllib.request.urlretrieve(
    "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/songys/Chatbot_data/master/ChatbotData.csv",
    filename="ChatBotDataMain.csv",
)

ChatData = pd.read_csv("ChatBotDataMain.csv")
ChatData = ChatData[:300]
# print(ChatData.head())

#dataset 만들기
dataset = aboutDataSets.ChatDataset(ChatData)

batch_size = 32
num_workers = 0

def collate_batch(batch):
    data = [item[0] for item in batch]
    mask = [item[1] for item in batch]
    label = [item[2] for item in batch]
    return torch.LongTensor(data), torch.LongTensor(mask), torch.LongTensor(label)
# 아래 collate_batch 변수때문에 여기 한번 더 호출.

#dataloader 선언
device = torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
train_set = aboutDataSets.ChatDataset(ChatData, max_len=40)
train_dataLoader = DataLoader(train_set,
                              batch_size=batch_size,
                              num_workers=num_workers,
                              shuffle=True,
                              collate_fn=collate_batch,) 

model.to(device) 
model.train()
lr = 3e-5
criterion = torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss(reduction='none')
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=lr)
epoch = 10
sneg = -1e18  


# 학습 시작

print("::start::")
for epoch in tqdm(range(epoch)): # 시각화를 위한 tqdm library
    for batch_idx, samples in enumerate(train_dataLoader):
        #print(batch_idx, samples)
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        token_ids, mask, label = samples
        out = model(token_ids)
        out = out.logits  # returns a new tensor with the logit of the elements of input
        mask_3d = mask.unsqueeze(dim=2).repeat_interleave(repeats=out.shape[2], dim=2)
        mask_out = torch.where(mask_3d == 1, out, sneg * torch.ones_like(out))
        loss = criterion(mask_out.transpose(2, 1), label)
        avg_loss = loss.sum() / mask.sum() # avg_loss[0] / avg_loss[1] <- loss 정규화
        avg_loss.backward()
        # 학습 끝
        optimizer.step()
print("end")
```

Comment: Your model is on cuda, but you never move either the `dataLoader` or `samples` there.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `token_ids, mask, label = samples` with `token_ids, mask, label = [t.to(device) for t in samples]`

This is because the samples generated by the dataloader is on CPU instead of CUDA by default. You have to move them to CUDA before performing `forward`.

Comment: Similar issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66091226/runtimeerror-expected-all-tensors-to-be-on-the-same-device-but-found-at-least/74514148#74514148