# Is there anything else I need to do besides calling model.to(device) for HuggingFace GPU?

Tags: python, pytorch, huggingface

I am new to using HuggingFace and the PyTorch ML ecosystem. I am trying to use a GPU device instead of the default CPU.

Can someone tell me if the following script is correct? The only thing I am calling is `lmhead_model.to(device)`.

I am not sure whether or not I need to move the `tokenizer`, `train_dataset`, `data_collator`, or anything else. Any insight would be appreciated for this beginner.

```
from transformers import GPT2Tokenizer
from transformers import GPT2LMHeadModel
from transformers import TextDataset
from transformers import DataCollatorForLanguageModeling
from transformers import Trainer
from transformers import TrainingArguments

# Load the GPT-2 tokenizer and LM head model
tokenizer    = GPT2Tokenizer.from_pretrained('gpt2')
lmhead_model = GPT2LMHeadModel.from_pretrained('gpt2')

# Load the training dataset and divide blocksize
train_dataset = TextDataset(
    tokenizer=tokenizer,
    file_path='tinyshakespeare.txt',
    block_size=64
)

# Create a data collator for preprocessing batches
data_collator = DataCollatorForLanguageModeling(
    tokenizer=tokenizer,
    mlm=False
)

# Optionally configure the model and pytorch w/ gpu
import torch
device = torch.device('cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu')
lmhead_model = lmhead_model.to(device)

if device.type == 'cuda':
    print('We are currently using a GPU')
else:
    print('We are currently using a CPU')

# Defining the training arguments
training_args = TrainingArguments(
    output_dir='tinyshakespeare',                  # output directory for checkpoints
    overwrite_output_dir=True,                     # overwrite any existing content

    per_device_train_batch_size=32,                # sample batch size for training
    dataloader_num_workers=0,                      # number of workers for dataloader
    max_steps=1000,                                # maximum number of training steps
    save_steps=1000,                               # after # steps checkpoints are saved
    save_total_limit=1,                            # maximum number of checkpoints to save

    prediction_loss_only=True,                     # only compute loss during prediction
    learning_rate=3e-4,                            # learning rate
    fp16=True if device.type == 'cuda' else False, # use 16-bit (mixed) precision

    optim='adamw_torch',                           # define the optimizer for training
    lr_scheduler_type='linear',                    # define the learning rate scheduler

    logging_steps=10,                              # after # steps logs are printed
    report_to='none',                              # report to wandb, tensorboard, etc.
)

# Performing the ML training loop
if __name__ == '__main__':
    trainer = Trainer(
        model=lmhead_model,
        args=training_args,
        data_collator=data_collator,
        train_dataset=train_dataset,
    )

    result = trainer.train()
    print_summary(result)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using one GPU, according to [tutorial here](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/perf_train_gpu_one), HF trainer seems to handle moving batch data to GPU automatically. Hence, it seems that moving the model to GPU looks adequate for your case. Though you can compare the total running times using CPU and GPU and assume there may be a problem if you don't see an improvement in speed when using GPU. Also, the code will raise a [runtime error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66091226/runtimeerror-expected-all-tensors-to-be-on-the-same-device-but-found-at-least) if you need to move something else to GPU.