# Pytorch-Scarf package RuntimeError: Expected all tensors to be on the same device, but found at least two devices, cuda:0 and cpu

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, runtime-error, tensor

RuntimeError: Expected all tensors to be on the same device, but found at least two devices, cuda:0 and cpu!

This comes when I run the example notebook from [this](https://github.com/clabrugere/pytorch-scarf) github repo.

Here is the code:

```
batch_size = 128

epochs = 1000  device = torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")

train_loader = DataLoader(train_ds, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True)

model = SCARF(  input_dim=train_ds.shape[1],  emb_dim=16,  corruption_rate=0.6,  ).to(device)  optimizer = Adam(model.parameters(), lr=0.001)  ntxent_loss = NTXent()

loss_history = []

for epoch in range(1, epochs + 1):  epoch_loss = train_epoch(model, ntxent_loss, train_loader, optimizer, device, epoch)  loss_history.append(epoch_loss)
```

### and here is the exact error:

```
RuntimeError Traceback (most recent call last)  Cell In [7], line 7  4 loss_history = []  6 for epoch in range(1, epochs + 1):  ----> 7 epoch_loss = train_epoch(model, ntxent_loss, train_loader, optimizer, device, epoch)  8 loss_history.append(epoch_loss)

File ~/pytorch-scarf/example/../example/utils.py:23, in train_epoch(model, criterion, train_loader, optimizer, device, epoch)  20 emb_anchor, emb_positive = model(anchor, positive)  22 # compute loss  ---> 23 loss = criterion(emb_anchor, emb_positive)  24 loss.backward()  26 # update model weights

File /opt/tljh/user/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py:1130, in Module._call_impl(self, *input, **kwargs)  1126 # If we don't have any hooks, we want to skip the rest of the logic in  1127 # this function, and just call forward.  1128 if not (self._backward_hooks or self._forward_hooks or self._forward_pre_hooks or _global_backward_hooks  1129 or _global_forward_hooks or _global_forward_pre_hooks):  -> 1130 return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)  1131 # Do not call functions when jit is used  1132 full_backward_hooks, non_full_backward_hooks = [], []

File ~/pytorch-scarf/example/../scarf/loss.py:39, in NTXent.forward(self, z_i, z_j)  37 mask = (~torch.eye(batch_size * 2, batch_size * 2, dtype=torch.bool)).float()  38 numerator = torch.exp(positives / self.temperature)  ---> 39 denominator = mask * torch.exp(similarity / self.temperature)  41 all_losses = -torch.log(numerator / torch.sum(denominator, dim=1))  42 loss = torch.sum(all_losses) / (2 * batch_size)

RuntimeError: Expected all tensors to be on the same device, but found at least two devices, cuda:0 and cpu!
```

When I run the code on a CPU only machine I don't get this same error. Because of how the data is created I am not able to confirm what tensor type it is (maybe this is the problem). I've confirmed that both emb_anchor and emb_positive before they are passed into criterion() are cuda (as suggested by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66091226/runtimeerror-expected-all-tensors-to-be-on-the-same-device-but-found-at-least) post to be a possible solution)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in `scarf/loss.py` file. You should replace the line:

```
mask = (~torch.eye(batch_size * 2, batch_size * 2, dtype=torch.bool)).float()
```

with

```
mask = (~torch.eye(batch_size * 2, batch_size * 2, dtype=torch.bool)).float().to(z_i.device)
```

The author forgot to move mask tensor to z_i.device