# "RuntimeError: Expected all tensors to be on the same device, but found at least two devices, cuda:0 and cpu" only while using laptop GPU

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch

I am getting this error while training a model using my GTX 3050 laptop GPU. But I am not getting this error while training the model in Google Colab.I followed the steps from this [article](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-setup-windows-machine-for-ml-dl-using-nvidia-graphics-card-cuda/) to train my model using my laptop GPU (I was previously using colab).

The model I am trying to train is [this](https://github.com/soojihan/HAN). Is there any possible explanation as to why this occurs?

Answer (score 0):

This happens when your input tensors allocated in CPU while your model allocated in GPU. You need to use `.to('cuda')` for passing your tensors to GPU. This has been noted in the code comments within the GitHub repository that you referenced.

Referring to this [code](https://github.com/soojihan/HAN/blob/main/depression_classifier.py), line 674:

```
 Notes: 1)Dataloaders give normal (non-cuda) tensors by default. They have to be manually cast using the Tensor.to() method.
```

You can also see this similar [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66091226/runtimeerror-expected-all-tensors-to-be-on-the-same-device-but-found-at-least?rq=2), for other answers.