# SGD Optimizer Custom Parameters

Tags: pytorch, linear-regression, gradient-descent

I am practicing using Pytorch and trying to implement a simple linear model.

I have initialized some random x and y inputs alongside some random parameters 'a' and 'b'.

```
import torch
torch.manual_seed(42)
x = torch.rand(100,1)
y = 1 + 2 * x + .1 * torch.rand(100, 1)
a = torch.randn(1, requires_grad=True)
b = torch.randn(1, requires_grad=True)
```

I would like to use gradient descent on a and b and update them as the model trains. I am using an sklearn linear regression model to compare my results to but they do not seem to be in accordance with each other as I would expect.

Here is the code to create the model

```
import torch.nn as nn
from torch.optim import SGD

#create simple linear model

class LinearModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.linear = nn.Linear(1, 1)

    def forward(self, x):
        return self.linear(x)

#loss function
criterion = torch.nn.MSELoss()

SGDmodel = LinearModel()
```

I am thinking my problem could possibly be within

```
sgd = torch.optim.SGD([a, b], lr=0.001, momentum=0.9, weight_decay=0.1)
```

Can I simply input my a and b parameters into the torch.optim function and have them update as the model is trained? or do I need to embed them into my model.parameters() in a different way somehow?

Here is the rest of my code if needed.

```
epochs = 1
inputs = x
targets = y

for epoch in range(epochs):
    
    sgd.zero_grad()
    yhat = SGDmodel(inputs)
    loss = criterion(yhat, targets)
    loss.backward()
    sgd.step()
    
    print(f'Loss: {loss}')
```

I am using the following to see what a and b are

```
print(SGDmodel.linear.weight.grad)
print(SGDmodel.linear.bias.grad)
tensor([[-3.1456]])
tensor([-5.4119])
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can I simply input my a and b parameters into the torch.optim function and have them update as the model is trained? or do I need to embed them into my model.parameters() in a different way somehow?

I think I figured it out!

I added `a` and `b` as parameters in my model by implementing `torch.nn.Parameter()`

I added them into the model, and called `self.weight` and `self.bias`.

```
class LinearModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.linear = nn.Linear(1, 1)
        self.weight = torch.nn.Parameter(a) #sets a as the weight in the linear layer
        self.bias = torch.nn.Parameter(b) # sets b as the bias in the linear layer
        
    def forward(self, x):
        return self.linear(x)
```

Now when I call my optimizer it will update the custom parameters I defined as `a` and `b`

```
sgd = torch.optim.SGD(SGDmodel.parameters(), lr=0.001, momentum=0.9, weight_decay=0.1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `a` and `b` are just tensors that have nothing to do with `SGDmodel`. The optimizer `sgd` should have the parameters of `SGDmodel`:

```py
sgd = torch.optim.SGD(SGDmodel.parameters(), lr=0.001, momentum=0.9, weight_decay=0.1)
```

For more details on how pytorch associates gradients and parameters between the loss and the optimizer see [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53975741/1714410).

Comment: Is there a way that I can make a and b the parameters that I want to be updated when referencing the SGD model parameters?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to initialize the params explicitly. When you create your model, its params are automatically created, and `model.parameters()` returns the params which you can see.

https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/basics/optimization_tutorial.html#optimizing-model-parameters
https://pytorch.org/tutorials/prototype/skip_param_init.html#skipping-module-parameter-initialization

Comment: Is there a way that I can make a and b the parameters that I want to be updated when referencing the SGD model parameters?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).