# Convert Tensoflow model to PyTorch model - model isn't learning

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, pytorch

I'm trying to port a tensorflow neural network to pytorch, as an exercise to familiarize myself with both / their nuances. This is the tensorflow network I'm porting to pytorch:

```
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing import sequence
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Activation
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Embedding
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv1D, GlobalMaxPooling1D
from tensorflow.keras.datasets import imdb

(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = imdb.load_data(num_words=5000)
x_train = sequence.pad_sequences(x_train, maxlen=400, padding="post")
x_test = sequence.pad_sequences(x_test, maxlen=400, padding="post")
model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(5000, 50, input_length=400))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Conv1D(250, 3, padding='valid',activation='relu',strides=1))
model.add(GlobalMaxPooling1D())
model.add(Dense(250))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.summary()
h2 = model.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size=32, epochs=10, validation_data=(x_test, y_test))
```

The shapes of each layer is shown below:

```
Model: "sequential"
_________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
 embedding (Embedding)       (None, 400, 50)           250000    
 dropout (Dropout)           (None, 400, 50)           0         
 conv1d (Conv1D)             (None, 398, 250)          37750     
 global_max_pooling1d (Globa  (None, 250)              0         
 lMaxPooling1D)                                                  
 dense (Dense)               (None, 250)               62750     
 dropout_1 (Dropout)         (None, 250)               0         
 activation (Activation)     (None, 250)               0         
 dense_1 (Dense)             (None, 1)                 251       
 activation_1 (Activation)   (None, 1)                 0         
                                                                 
=================================================================
Total params: 350,751
Trainable params: 350,751
Non-trainable params: 0
```

And the output of the tensorflow model is:

```
Epoch 1/10
loss: 0.4043 - accuracy: 0.8021 - val_loss: 0.2764 - val_accuracy: 0.8854
Epoch 2/10
loss: 0.2332 - accuracy: 0.9052 - val_loss: 0.2690 - val_accuracy: 0.8888
Epoch 3/10
loss: 0.1598 - accuracy: 0.9389 - val_loss: 0.2948 - val_accuracy: 0.8832
Epoch 4/10
loss: 0.1112 - accuracy: 0.9600 - val_loss: 0.3015 - val_accuracy: 0.8906
Epoch 5/10
loss: 0.0810 - accuracy: 0.9700 - val_loss: 0.3057 - val_accuracy: 0.8868
Epoch 6/10
loss: 0.0537 - accuracy: 0.9811 - val_loss: 0.4055 - val_accuracy: 0.8868
Epoch 7/10
loss: 0.0408 - accuracy: 0.9860 - val_loss: 0.4083 - val_accuracy: 0.8852
Epoch 8/10
loss: 0.0411 - accuracy: 0.9845 - val_loss: 0.4789 - val_accuracy: 0.8789
Epoch 9/10
loss: 0.0380 - accuracy: 0.9862 - val_loss: 0.4828 - val_accuracy: 0.8827
Epoch 10/10
loss: 0.0329 - accuracy: 0.9879 - val_loss: 0.4999 - val_accuracy: 0.8825
```

Here's what I have in my PyTorch port over:

```
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader
from torch.utils.data import Dataset
import torch
from tqdm import tqdm
import torch.nn.functional as F
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score

class CustomDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
    
    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.y)

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        return self.x[idx], self.y[idx]
    
train_dataloader = DataLoader(CustomDataset(torch.Tensor(x_train), torch.Tensor(y_train)), batch_size=32, shuffle=True)
test_dataloader = DataLoader(CustomDataset(torch.Tensor(x_test), torch.Tensor(y_test)), batch_size=32, shuffle=True)

class MyModel(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, vocab_size=5000, input_len=400, embedding_dims=50, kernel_size=3, filters=250, hidden_dims=250):
        super(MyModel, self).__init__()
        self.embedding_dims = embedding_dims
        self.input_len = input_len
        self.embedding = torch.nn.Embedding(num_embeddings=vocab_size, embedding_dim=embedding_dims)
        self.dropout1 = torch.nn.Dropout(p=0.2)
        self.conv1d = torch.nn.Conv1d(in_channels=embedding_dims, out_channels=filters, kernel_size=kernel_size, padding=(0,), stride=1)
        self.pool = torch.nn.AdaptiveMaxPool1d(1)
        self.linear1 = torch.nn.Linear(in_features=hidden_dims, out_features=hidden_dims)
        self.dropout2 = torch.nn.Dropout(p=0.2)
        self.activation = torch.nn.ReLU()
        self.output = torch.nn.Linear(in_features=hidden_dims, out_features=1)
        self.activation2 = torch.nn.Sigmoid()

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.dropout1(self.embedding(x.type(torch.LongTensor)))
        x = self.conv1d(x.view(-1, self.embedding_dims, self.input_len))
        x = self.pool(x)
        x = self.activation(self.dropout2(self.linear1(x.view(-1,x.size()[1]))))
        x = self.activation2(self.output(x))
        return x

class FitTorchModel():
    def __init__(self, model, num_epochs=10, steps_per_epoch=782):
        self.model = model
        self.epochs = num_epochs
        self.steps_per_epoch = steps_per_epoch
        
    def fit(self, train_dataloader, test_dataloader):
        opt = torch.optim.Adam(self.model.parameters(), lr=0.001)
        crit = torch.nn.BCELoss(reduction = "mean")
        history_df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ["Loss", "Accuracy", "Val_Loss", "Val_Acc"])
        for epoch in range(self.epochs):
            self.model.train()
            print(f"Epoch {epoch}")
            epoch_loss = 0
            epoch_acc = 0
            it = iter(train_dataloader)
            for step in tqdm(range(self.steps_per_epoch)):
                opt.zero_grad()
                x, y = next(it)
                y_pred = self.model(x).view(-1)
                loss = crit(y_pred, y)     
                epoch_loss += loss.item()
                epoch_acc += accuracy_score(y==1, y_pred > 0.5)
                loss.backward()
                opt.step()
            val_loss, val_acc = self.predict_proba(test_dataloader, crit)
            df = pd.DataFrame({"Loss": epoch_loss/(step+1), 
                               "Accuracy": epoch_acc/(step+1),
                               "Val_Loss": val_loss, "Val_Acc": val_acc}, index=[0]) 
            history_df = pd.concat((history_df, df), ignore_index=True) 
        return history_df

    def predict_proba(self, test_dataloader, crit):
        self.model.eval()
        val_loss = 0
        val_acc = 0
        it = iter(test_dataloader)
        with torch.no_grad():    
            for step in tqdm(range(self.steps_per_epoch)):
                x,y = next(it)
                y_pred = self.model(x).view(-1)
                batch_loss = crit(y_pred, y)
                val_loss += batch_loss.item()
                val_acc += accuracy_score(y==1, y_pred > 0.5)
        return  val_loss/(step+1), val_acc/(step+1)

ftm = FitTorchModel(model=MyModel(), num_epochs=10, steps_per_epoch=782)
history_df = ftm.fit(train_dataloader, test_dataloader)
```

The shape of each layer is:

```
After embedding layer: torch.Size([32, 400, 50])
After dropout1 layer: torch.Size([32, 400, 50])
After convolution1d layer: torch.Size([32, 250, 398])
After maxpooling layer: torch.Size([32, 250, 1])
After linear1 layer: torch.Size([32, 250])
After dropout2 layer: torch.Size([32, 250])
After activation layer: torch.Size([32, 250])
After output layer: torch.Size([32, 1])
After activation2 layer: torch.Size([32, 1])
```

The output of the pytorch model training is:

```
       Loss  Accuracy  Val_Loss   Val_Acc
0  0.697899  0.505874  0.692495  0.511629
1  0.693063  0.503477  0.693186  0.503637
2  0.693190  0.496044  0.693149  0.499201
3  0.693181  0.501359  0.693082  0.502038
4  0.693169  0.503237  0.693234  0.495964
5  0.693177  0.500240  0.693154  0.500679
6  0.693069  0.507473  0.693258  0.498881
7  0.693948  0.500320  0.693145  0.501598
8  0.693196  0.499640  0.693164  0.496324
9  0.693170  0.500759  0.693140  0.501918
```

Couple things: the accuracy hovers around guessing (this is a binary classification task), no matter how many epochs have passed. Secondly, the training loss barely improves. I set the learning rate to the default learning rate described by [tensorflow's Adam Optimizer docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/optimizers/Adam). What else am I missing here? I had some trouble with the input / output dimensions for the various layers - did I mess those up at all?

Comment: Why are you flattening your tensor (on the `y_pred = ` line)? Side note you should define your iterator (`iter(train_dataloader)`) outside your step loop... you are currently initializing a new iterator at every *step* iteration, it should be at every *epoch* iteration.

Comment: Thanks for the tip about the iterator! I fixed that and was hopeful that was the issue, but results stayed the same. I flatted y_pred because the original y labels are all scalars, and the model was wrapping the single scalar predictions in a list, so in order to compare apples to apples I had to flatten it. Hopefully that makes sense, etc.

Comment: The iterator does not have effects on model's performance because you use `shuffle=True`. About the shapes of your output, could you provide its shape before flattening as well as the shape of the label `y`?

Comment: Hi, @Ivan - just updated my post to include the output dimension of each layer for both the Tensorflow and my PyTorch port over version of the model. For batch size=32, the dimensionality the model outputs without me forcing it to a scalar vector using .view(-1) is [32 1]. The dimension of y is [32]. So I force the y_preds to [32] as well using .view(-1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some observations:

- Use BCEWithLogitsLoss as loss on the output of the last linear layer, before the sigmoid. This includes the sigmoid activation in a more numerically stable fashion.
- The TensorFlow model has a ReLU after the Convolution, the pytorch implementations does not.

In general, for debugging, one might want to look at `weight.grad` of some of your weights after the `loss.backward()` and see if gradients calculated. Also printing out the value of one of the weights in each iteration to see if your optimizer actually changes the weights can help...

Also, it can depend on the input data:
(Are you sure that x_test is scaled correctly?)
If you are transforming your inputs to `Long` before embedding them and all x_test, for example, are floats between 0 and 1, they will all be converted to 0! And the network will have a hard time predicting the labels from all zeros as constant input!

But now to the actual issue in this particular case:
Be careful with .view! It might not do what you expect. It just reshapes the tensor but does not move the data around.
What you really want is `.moveaxes(-1,2)` instead!!

```
        Loss    Accuracy    Val_Loss    Val_Acc
0   0.573489    0.671715    0.402601    0.819413
1   0.376908    0.830163    0.33786     0.850783
2   0.308343    0.868646    0.296171    0.872323
3   0.258806    0.893342    0.319121    0.865849
4   0.227044    0.907649    0.3172      0.868326
5   0.202789    0.918478    0.281184    0.886549
6   0.179744    0.928549    0.291027    0.886589
7   0.161205    0.93702     0.329196    0.879156
8   0.145447    0.944094    0.294914    0.889746
9   0.133034    0.949568    0.291476    0.889826
```

After adding the relu after the convolution and, more importantly, fixing the view!

```py
class MyModel(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, vocab_size=5000, input_len=400, embedding_dims=50, kernel_size=3, filters=250, hidden_dims=250):
        super(MyModel, self).__init__()
        self.embedding_dims = embedding_dims
        self.input_len = input_len
        self.embedding = torch.nn.Embedding(num_embeddings=vocab_size, embedding_dim=embedding_dims)
        self.dropout1 = torch.nn.Dropout(p=0.2)
        self.conv1d = torch.nn.Conv1d(in_channels=embedding_dims, out_channels=filters, kernel_size=kernel_size, padding=(0,), stride=1)
        self.pool = torch.nn.AdaptiveMaxPool1d(1)
        self.linear1 = torch.nn.Linear(in_features=hidden_dims, out_features=hidden_dims)
        self.dropout2 = torch.nn.Dropout(p=0.2)
        self.activation = torch.nn.ReLU()
        self.output = torch.nn.Linear(in_features=hidden_dims, out_features=1)
        self.activation2 = torch.nn.Sigmoid()

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.dropout1(self.embedding(x.type(torch.LongTensor)))
        x = self.activation(self.conv1d(x.moveaxis(-1,-2)))
        x = self.pool(x).squeeze(-1)
        x = self.activation(self.dropout2(self.linear1(x)))
        x = self.activation2(self.output(x))
        return x
```

Comment: Great ideas!! I learned from you! I did everything you told me, and when I print(self.model.output.weights.grad), all values of the gradients are zero. How do I figure out why the optimizer isn't changing the weights?

Comment: I think it has something to do with something being detached from the computation graph, like similar to: https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/optimizer-not-updating-the-weights-parameters/147726/5. I converted my numpy objects to torch.Tensors though in my data loader step I thought

Comment: I believe you might be printing the .grad at the wrong place, it should be directly after the loss.backward call. Your issue is more likely the .view shuffling around data from different time points in the sequence...

Comment: YES YES YES YES YES!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! So PUMPED! Thank you so much for your awesome brain!

Comment: did you set self.model.eval() in your predict_proba()? I'm getting training accuracies in >90, but my validation accuracies are still hovering around 50! When I remove self.model.eval(), though, the validation accuracies pop up again. Any idea why?

Answer (score 1):

What is `tinymodel` you init `opt` with in `fit` function:

```py
opt = torch.optim.Adam(tinymodel.parameters(), lr=0.001)
```

It seems like your optimizer is not working on the right model (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53975741/1714410) on the relation between the optimizer and the parameters of the model).

You need to replace this line in `fit` function:

```py
        
    def fit(self, train_dataloader, test_dataloader):
        opt = torch.optim.Adam(self.model.parameters(), lr=0.001)
        # ...
```

---

Additionally, you are using `Dropout` layer that has different behavior in train and test.
You should add `self.model.train()` and `self.model.eval()` at the beginning of your `fit` and `predict_proba` functions respectively.

Comment: great catch with self.model.paramters(), and you're right that I was conflating model.eval() with torch.no_grad(). They do different things and both are needed. I was sad to see that it still didn't change my output - which still hovers around chance. I am stumped!

Comment: @lrthistlethwaite please update your question to reflect your use of `self.model.train()` and `self.model.eval()`.

Comment: Just updated! Good idea!